# How to get value from string template in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String template like this:

> "Thanks, this is your value : [value]. And this is your account number : [accountNumber]"

And i have inputs like this:

> input 1 : "Thanks, this is your value : 100. And this is your account number : 219AD098"
>
> input 2 : "Thanks, this is your value : 150. And this is your account number : 90582374"
>
> input 3 : "Thanks, this is your value : 200. And this is your account number : 18A47"

I want output like this:

> output 1 : "[value] = 100 | [accountNumber] = 219AD098"
>
> output 2 : "[value] = 150 | [accountNumber] = 90582374"
>
> output 3 : "[value] = 200 | [accountNumber] = 18A47"

How to do that? Maybe using Regex?

note : the template is not fixed.. the only thing that fixed is [value] and [accountNumber]..

Comment: Use a regex if the template is fixed and get value in group 1 and account number in group 2.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: No, template will easily changed, so i cant hard coded it..
maybe later i will change template like this "Ohh [value], this [accountNumber]" And input "Ohh 123, this ABC", and i want output like this, "[value] = 123 | [accountNumber] = ABC"

Comment: @b11r did I answer you or can I help you with anything else?

Comment: @dirtydexter ur answer seems good, but can u show me how to use that Regex in Java?

Answer (score 4):

use this `regex`

```
(?<=value : )(\d+)|(?<=number : )(.+)(?=")
```

this will extract both the values from the lines that you want. after getting them you can concatenate them with anything you want like your output string.

the code to use this `regex` will be like this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=value : )(\d+)|(?<=number : )(.+)(?=\")");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(SOURCE_TEXT_LINE);
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
 allMatches.add(matcher.group());
}
```

so this way you will get the matched values in this array list, of you can use a simple array if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, that regex looks very succinct! Could you please elaborate on how he can then get the values he needs? Is that with a `Matcher`, or how?

Comment: Sorry I'm new in regex, can u show me how to use that regex in java?

Comment: @b11r I have edited the answer to show you how you can use this in java. If there are some confusion then please ask, or if there is anything else that I can help you with. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied it helps everybody on the network.

Comment: @dirtydexter is a difference between `(?<=value : )(\d+)|(?<=number : )(.+)(?=")`et `(?<=value : )(\d+)|(?<=number : )(.+)\"`

Comment: @cl-r yeah in the other `"` is also included but that is not required. we want to match it, but it should not be included in our result.

Comment: @dirtydexter Thanks, I've forgotten the result impact

Answer (score 1):

```
    String text = "Thanks, this is your value : 100. And this is your account number : 219AD098";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("Thanks, this is your value : (\\d+). And this is your account number : (\\w+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    matcher.find();
    String outputText = "[value] = " + matcher.group(1)
            + " | [accountNumber] = " + matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println(outputText);
```

Comment: While you were posting he said that template will easily changed :(

Comment: i realize just now :(

Answer (score 0):

is is easy to do without regex too:

```
String input = getInput();

String[] inputLines = input.split("\n");
String output = "";
int counter = 1;

for(string line : inputLines)
{
   int subValStart = line.indexOf("value : ");
   string val = line.substring(subValStart, line.indexOf("|") - subValStart);
   string accNum = line.substring("account number : ");
   output += "output " + counter + " :\"[value] = "+ val + " | [accountNumber] = " + accNum + "\"\n"; 
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: but the template I used is not fixed.. I can changed template to "[value] halo [accountNumber]" And input string "100 halo 2195023" and i want output "value = 100 | accountNumber = 2195023" if i changed template, your code wont help

Comment: @b11r true, but the regex won't help you either. you need some format for playing with strings...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [StringUtils.subStringBefore](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
   String sCurrentLine = CURRENT_LINE;
   String[] splitedValue = sCurrentLine.split(":");

   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   stringBuilder.append(splitedValue[0].replace("input", "output"));
   stringBuilder.append(": \"[value] = "+StringUtils.substringBefore(splitedValue[2], "."));
   stringBuilder.append(" | [accountNumber] = "+splitedValue[3]);
```

Comment: but the template I used is not fixed.. I can changed template to "[value] halo [accountNumber]" And input string "100 halo 2195023" and i want output "value = 100 | accountNumber = 2195023" if i changed template, your code wont help

Comment: then seperate all the need value. And then dynamically create the template.If you can change the template anyone code wont help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression.

Here is full example

```
package snippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CoffeeDOMException, IOException {
        String test = "Thanks, this is your value : 100 . And this is your account number : 219AD098";
        String valueExpression = "\\svalue\\s:([^.]+)";
        String accExpresion = "\\saccount\\snumber\\s:([^$]+)";
        System.out.println("Value:" + runSubRegex(valueExpression, test));
        System.out.println("Account:" + runSubRegex(accExpresion, test));

    }

    private static String runSubRegex(String regex, String tag) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(tag);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Output

```
Value: 100 
Account :  219AD098
```

Comment: but the template I used is not fixed.. I can changed template to "[value] halo [accountNumber]" And input string "100 halo 2195023" and i want output "value = 100 | accountNumber = 2195023" if i changed template, your code wont help

Comment: If you are thinking of changing template like that then even Jon Skeet wont be able to help you. First decide how the template you want and add that to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Just check it out.

```
String template = "Thanks, this is your value : -XXXX-. And this is your account number : -XXXX- -XXXX- Value,Account Number";
String input = "Thanks, this is your value : 100. And this is your account number : 219AD098";

/*String template = "You can use -XXXX- mehod to read values from -XXXX- Value 1,value 2";
String input = "You can use this mehod to read values from custom string template";*/

String[] splitValue = template.split("-XXXX-");
for (String splitValueTemp : splitValue) {
    input = input.replace(splitValueTemp, "!");
}

List<String> value = Arrays.asList(input.split("!"));
List<String> Key = Arrays.asList(splitValue[splitValue.length - 1].split(","));
if (value != null && value.size() > 1) {
    int iCnt = 0;
    for (String opValue : value.subList(1, value.size())) {
        if (Key.size() > iCnt) {
            System.out.println(Key.get(iCnt).trim() + " : " + opValue.trim());
        }
        iCnt++;
    }
}
```

O/P:
Value : 100
Account Number : 219AD098